# Reuse a LINQ To Entities statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, reusability

I have the following `Select` expression that will be performed database-side:

```
        var model = new ProductListViewModel()
        {
            Products = products
                .Select(q => new ProductViewModel()
                {
                    // Other mapping
                    Name = q.LanguageKey.LanguageValues.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LanguageKeyID == currentLanguageID && p.Active).Value,
                })
                .OrderBy(q => q.Name)
        };
```

As you can see, the Name part is quite long, and other part of my program also use the same logic. Therefore, I would like to reuse it (not entire Select statement, just the Name mapping part).

I tried to write a function that only use the entity:

```
public static string GetProductName(Product product, int languageID)
{
    return product.LanguageKey.LanguageValues.AsQueryable()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => q.LanguageID == languageID && q.Active).Value;
}
```

However, on calling the method, I (obviously) receive the error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method {X} method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

I have searched through many articles on StackOverflow, but most solve the problem of reusing entire Select expression. Is it possible to reuse it? Or do I have to create database Stored Procedure or Function?

Comment: Does it literally say {X} in the error message?

Comment: Is .Merge one of methods you've tried and can't use? https://coding.abel.nu/2013/01/merging-expression-trees-to-reuse-in-linq-queries/

Comment: @dlxeon No, I haven't tried it yet. Sorry I am having a power down here and have to use my phone, so I cannot try anything right now. Will reply as soon as possible. Thamk you for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx).

First, you need to modify your method to return an expression like this:

```
public Expression<Func<Product, string>> CreateExpression(int languageID)
{
    return product => product.LanguageKey.LanguageValues.AsQueryable()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => q.LanguageID == languageID && q.Active).Value;
}
```

By the way, I don't think that you need to invoke `.AsQueryable()` here.

Then you can do the following:

```
var expression = CreateExpression(currentLanguageID);

var model = new ProductListViewModel()
{
    Products = products.AsExpandable()
        .Select(q => new ProductViewModel()
        {
            // Other mapping
            Name = expression.Invoke(q),
        })
        .OrderBy(q => q.Name)
};
```

Notice the `.AsExpandable()` call on the `products` variable.

This method is from LINQKit, and it creates a wrapper around the `IQueryable` (in your case `products`) to enable using expressions from inside your lambda expressions.

Also notice the `Invoke` method that is also coming from LINQKit. It allows you to use the `expression` inside your other expression, i.e., `q => new ProductViewModel(...`.