# 'Invoke' node is not supported in LINQ when nesting Expression Functions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I am trying to nest `Expression Functions`, I've tried multiple things (`Invoke`, `Compile` etc.) and read topics about this exception, but did not see any case appending when nesting expression functions. I don't know much about it, it is pretty new for me, I guess I must have missed something very simple.
My aim is just to be able to nest expressions so that `GetAbilities` could be used in multiple other expressions without having to duplicate its code.

How could I achieve such a thing ?

```
public static Expression<Func<User, bool>> Test
    {
        get
        {
            Expression<Func<User, bool>> res = (u => GetAbilities.Compile()(u).Any());
            return res;
        }
    }

    public static Expression<Func<User, IEnumerable<Ability>>> GetAbilities
    {
        get
        {
            Expression<Func<User, IEnumerable<Ability>>> res = u => u.AllAbilities.Where(a => a.Type == Ability.TypeE.Initial);
            return res;
        }
    }
```

In the above example, when retrieving the results of `Test` I got the follwing exception :

> The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

***UPDATE***

See working accepted solution below :)
Since this is now working, would anybody know what should be done about those unmapped properties ? Concretly, the `GetAbilities` method refers to another another one in `User` class, but I can't use it directly in queries since this is an unmapped method. So the question is should I leave the `Abilities` property in `User` class for internal use and static `GetAbilities` for queries purpose (but this is duplicating code in a way), or may be compile and invoke the static `GetAbilities` in the `User` class ?

Leave it as is it does not seems very clean and maintainable (seems quite simple here but real functions are more complex):

```
// Used for queries
public static Expression<Func<User, IEnumerable<Ability>>> GetAbilities
{
    get
    {
        Expression<Func<User, IEnumerable<Ability>>> res = u => u.AllAbilities.Where(a => a.Type == Ability.TypeE.Initial);
        return res;
    }
}

// Used for internal purpose
public IEnumerable<Ability> Abilities
{
    get
    {
        return AllAbilities.Where(a => a.Type == Ability.TypeE.Initial);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx). Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379234/reuse-a-linq-to-entities-statement

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems to work fine :) You can post it as answer, I'll accept it. Just a thing though, won't using `AsExpandable` have any performance issue ? It does not enumerate the entire collection, right ?

Comment: Hi Flash. Don't worry, it just rewrites the expression tree. And using `AsExpandable()` is not strongly necessary if you `Expand` all your expression invokations.

Comment: Hi Ivan :D Thanks for your reply, I am glad to hear that it's okay to use it, you mean I could call `Expand` on `Test` and `GetAbilities` `res` variable instead of calling `AsExpandable` on entire collection ?

Comment: See the Yacoub's answer. I would personally shorten it to a static readonly field/property like `public static Expression<Func<User, bool>> Test { get; } = Linq.Expr((User u) => GetAbilities.Invoke(u).Any()).Expand();`

Comment: Yes, I tried to make it work with a very simple example but in reality functions are more complex. Thanks a lot to both of you, I know this is not really the original question but by any chance, would you have any advice about the update in main post ?

Comment: Well, you could reuse the logic by adding `public static Func<User, IEnumerable<Ability>> GetAbilitiesFunc { get; } = GetAbilities.Compile();` and then `public IEnumerable<Ability> Abilities => GetAbilitiesFunc(this);`

Comment: Thanks a lot Ivan, I'll go as you said, your suggestions are always relevant and already helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to do something like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<User, bool>> Test
{
    get
    {
        //Use one expression inside another via Invoke
        Expression<Func<User, bool>> res = (u => GetAbilities.Invoke(u).Any());

        return res.Expand(); //Expand to create a full expression

        //The result would be the same as if you have used
        //u => u.AllAbilities.Where(a => a.Type == Ability.TypeE.Initial).Any()

    }
}
```